# Why does JSch SCP not write the files in a loop to the remote host?

Tags: foreach, scp, jsch

I want (or to be more precisely) I have to use JSch to copy files in a loop to a remote host using SCP.
I am doing it this way:

```
public long writeFiles (Map<String, byte[]> files) {
    long count = 0;
    try {
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

        count = files.entrySet().stream().filter( k -> k.getKey() != null ).peek((k) -> {
            String command =
                    getProperty("scp.bin.path") + "scp -t " + getProperty("scp.target.path") +
                    "/" + k.getKey() + " ";
            System.out.println("Sending command: " + command);

            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            try {
                channel.connect();
                System.out.println("Connected to channel to E@syMail Server " +
                                   getProperty("scp.host.ip"));
                command = "C0644 " + k.getValue().length + " " + k.getKey() + "\n";
                System.out.println("Sending C644 command: " + command);
                ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
                final OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
                out.write(command.getBytes());
                out.flush();
                out.write(k.getValue());
                out.flush();
                out.write(new byte[]{0}, 0, 1);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                logger.error(ex.toString());
            } catch (JSchException e) {
                logger.error(e.toString());
            }
            System.out.println("File written to " + getProperty("scp.host.ip") + ":" +
                               getProperty("scp.target.path") + "/" + k.getKey());
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("chmod " + getProperty("scp.chmod") + "-R " +
                                               k.getKey());

            channel.disconnect();
        }).count();
        session.disconnect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        logger.error(e.toString());
    }

    final MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat(getProperty("msg.scp.done") + "\n");
    logger.info(mf.format(new Object[]{Long.valueOf(count),
                                       getProperty("scp.host.ip"),
                                       getProperty("scp.target.path")}));

    return count;
}
```

...but when I look into the target folder, the files are not copied to there. 
What am I doing wrong?? I oriented myself at the example [JSch ScpTo](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html)

EDIT 1:
Right before executing the SCP command I tried to do a remote *ls* this way:

```
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("ls -lisa;");
    channel.connect();

    String msg=null;
    while((msg=in.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
```

...and it's doing its job very well!

Comment: You should use SFTP for this instead of SCP, if that's an option.

Comment: What is the actual scp command that you end up running on the remote system? What does your actual C0644 command say?

Comment: Does your question imply that the code works when not executed *"in a loop"*?

Comment: Good hint, Martin. I tried that but unfortunately the file is not written even if I do i t once/not in a loop.

Comment: SFTP unfortunately is no option right now.

Comment: @Kenster:
What dou you mean with 'What does your actual C0644 command say?'
How can I check this?

Comment: `command = "C0644 " + k.getValue().length + " " + k.getKey() + "\n";` What string does this line of code end up producing?

Comment: I do a System.out.println() of the generated command in the loop. It is showing: C0644 122880 VA_21003153OHNE.csv (with a "\n" at the end).
I even tried to send the file's content chunkwise using a ByteArrayInputStream each chunk of 1024 bytes...with the same result.

Comment: Doing this from the CMD directly works and the file is effectively copied to the remote system:
C:/Program Files (x86)/ICW/bin/scp" -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\ICW\.ssh\id_rsa" VA_21003153OHNE.csv" puser@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:"/the/target/path/VA_21003153OHNE.csv"